# Can a two player realm hold one host and two players?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On Minecraft Pocket Edition,  there's two player realms and ten player realms. Can two player realms have a host and two online players?

Answer (score 2):

Here is what [Minecraft.net](https://minecraft.net/en-us/realms/?ref=fm) says about this:

> Pick this option to own a realm which supports simultaneous play for you and two friends.

So it is you *and* two friends, so yes, it is three people total. It works the same way with the ten person realms.