# How many players can I invite to a 2-player realm?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition-realms

Let's say I Get a 2 player realm and I send an invite to 5 friends, let's call them a, b, c, d and e. I want all 5 to play therefore is it possible for a and b to play then b logs off and d plays. Basically can 5 people have access to the realm but only 2 can play it at a time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a two player realm hold one host and two players?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/317800/can-a-two-player-realm-hold-one-host-and-two-players) Although, admittedly, I don't fully grasp what you're trying to say with your last clause.

Comment: @Joachim I think he's asking how many invitations he can send out rather than what the capacity of the server is. I've suggested an edit.

Comment: Definitely not a duplicate. This question asks about how many invites can be sent, while the linked question asks about how many players can be on the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can send out as many invitations as you want, but in terms of joining, whoever is the first to join, will be the one who joins. The rest will be denied access.

Answer (score 1):

There can be an infinite quantity of players able to join the realm, there can be an infinite quantity of invites out at a single time.

However, a realm can only have 3 concurrent players, 2 non-owners and one slot reserved for the owner only.

Let's say you were the owner, you invite 20 players to the realm, all 20 can accept, and let's say they do.

Only two of your friends can be playing at a time, the other 18 will be unable to join, you, on the other hand, have one slot reserved for yourself.

You can have an infinite quantity of players **ABLE** to join, but only two can **PLAY** at a time.